# Bash Script - OSX - Find file > Set path of file directory> Remove specify file by the name

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

Hello its my first "post" so I please for forgiving :)

Basically I need to locate file which is placed in one of few folders under the specify path for example it could be "/Folders". Directory is always placed directly on the ROOT and the content names are various. Thats why I cant set path to specify folder which one include wanted file.

I know how it should works but Im beginner in the scripting title. Below I like to present my "scheme" of the script.

1. Find file by the name under /Folders path with grep option to close as much ich possible searching results for example name of the file could be "WantedOne".
2. Copy to clipboard result of search probably best way is PBCOPY but not sure.
3. Change directory to the path placed into clipboard WITHOUT file name at the end of path for example "/Folders/XYZ/" where file "WantedOne" is placed inside.
4. Echo "Found ;- )"

Comment: Is there a reason to use `grep` instead of `find`?

Answer (score 1):

It's the `find` command you want to use. Here are some examples to get you started:

```
# find file with exact name, somewhere under a folder and its sub-folders
find /path/to/folder -name wanted.txt

# same thing, but multiple folders to search, there can be even more
find /path/to/folder1 /path/to/folder2 -name wanted.txt

# find file with name starting with "wanted"
find /path/to/folder -name 'wanted.*'

# find file with "ted" anywhere in the name
find /path/to/folder -name '*ted*'
```

The man page explains the many more interesting options. For example you can control the depth of the search. Look for some tutorials on the web for more examples.

If instead of printing the found paths you just want to echo "Found one":

```
find /path/to/folder -name '*wanted*' -printf "Found one\n" | head -n 1
```

If that doesn't work in osx (I cannot test right now), then use this instead:

```
find /path/to/folder -name '*wanted*' -exec echo "Found one" \; | head -n 1
```

Comment: Actually iv problem with section 3 in my post. Change direction to found one. 

This is what i have.

find /Folders -name wanted | grep "/wanted" | pbcopy ... and it works correctly with pbpaste but dunno how inject info from pbpaste to change direction command.